# What is this syntax inside ruby clases?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery #What is this syntax? When is this executed and how to create one?
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  attr_accessible :body, :commenter, :post
end
```

In the first case,  I understand ApplicationController is a new Derived class of class called `Base` in the module ActionController. What happens in the next line? Is `protect_from_forgery` a method in base class or in module ActionController? What is it called? I couldn't find in ruby classes documentation. I tried creating a method in base class but got errors like below. How do I create such special commands which can be used in a class?

```
class Base
  def foo
    @name = "foo"
  end
end

class Der < Base
  foo
  def bar
    @dummy = "bar"
  end
end
```

Error:

```
expr1.rb:62:in `<class:Der>': undefined local variable or method `foo' for Der:Class (NameError)
    from expr1.rb:61:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Those are rails methods, not ruby.  That's why you can't find them. [forgery_protection](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/RequestForgeryProtection/ClassMethods.html).  It's a class method in [ActionController](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/e7feaff70f13b56a0507e9f4dfaf3ebc361cb8e6/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb#L102)

Comment: @japed How do I create such method? When is it executed? Why my example didn't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`protect_from_forgery`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/RequestForgeryProtection/ClassMethods.html#method-i-protect_from_forgery) is a class-method defined in one of the modules included in `ActionController::Base` and made available to the child class when you inherit from `ActionController::Base`.

This kind of methods in Rails are sometimes called "macro" as they are class methods that enables some specific feature (sometimes also using metaprogramming to define extra methods or helpers). In reality, the term "macro" is incorrect as Ruby has no macro. They are nothing else than class methods.

The most important detail to keep in mind is that, when they are used in the class-definition. these methods are run at code-evaluation and not at runtime.

```
class Base
  def foo_instance
    p "foo instance"
  end

  def self.foo_class
    p "foo class"
  end
end

class Der < Base
  foo_class
  def bar
    p "bar"
  end
end

Der.new.bar
```

will produce

```
"foo class"
"bar"
```

Answer (score 1):

To create class methods you can do either of these.

```
class Base
  def self.foo
  end
end

class Base
  class << self
    def foo
    end
  end
end
```

Because they are class methods you call them on the class

`Base.foo`

Answer (score 1):

So what you're talking about are "class methods" - class methods are methods that are defined on the class itself, not on the *instance* of the class.  Note the following:

```
class Greeter
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end

  def greet
    "hello, #{@name}"
  end
end

Greeter.new("bob").greet # => "hello, bob"
```

`#greet` is an instance method on the `Greeter` classes.  However, `.new` is a "class method" - which is a method called on the class itself.  Attempting to call `.greet` on the `Greeter` class would result in a `NameError`:

```
Greeter.greet # ! NameError
```

So if you want to define such a "class method", you have to use one of the following syntaxes:

```
class Greeter
  def self.greet(name)
    "hello, #{name}"
  end

  class << self
    def greet(name)
      "hello, #{name}"
    end
  end

  class << Greeter
    # same as above
  end
end

def Greeter.greet(name)
  "hello, #{name}"
end
```

Going back to the original question, if you reopen the greeter class, you can now use the `.greet` method:

```
class Greeter
  greet "bob" # => "hello, bob"
end
```

This also applies for subclassing, as well:

```
class Host < Greeter
  greet "bob" # => "hello, bob"
end
```

This is how Rails provides these methods - they define class methods on the base class, most often `ActiveRecord::Base`, which you can then use - explaining methods such as `protect_from_forgery`.

Answer (score 1):

protect_from_forgery is a class method:Could look like this

```
 def protect_from_forgery(options = {})
        self.forgery_protection_strategy = protection_method_class(options[:with] || :null_session)
        self.request_forgery_protection_token ||= :authenticity_token
        prepend_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, options
        append_after_action :verify_same_origin_request
      end
```

So its inherited by application controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
```

Your example could be written like this:

```
class Base
  class << self
    def foo
      @name = "foo"
    end
  end
end

class Der < Base
  foo     #class method from Base
  def bar
    @dummy = "bar"
  end
end
```

To see foo's values

```
Der.foo.inspect
```

Answer (score -2):

Its inheritance. In your child class you can use all method inhertited from parrent class.
Firstly you can call methods on class instance.
In your example you can do sth like this:

```
    base_object = Base.new
    base_object.foo

    der_object = Der.new
    der_object.bar
```

but also thanks to inheritance you can do sth like this:

```
    der_object.foo
```

Here is simple tutorial for ruby inheritance with examples:
http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_inheritance.html

happy coding!

Comment: sure, as I said you need to call instance methods on instance of class, on some class object. To undestand this approach I recommend you to read some OOP tutorials. This one is quite good: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_object_oriented.htm